# Как настроить соединение с SQL сервером в WPF приложении?

Tags: c#, wpf, sql

Пытаюсь настроить работу WPF приложения с SQL Server, по примеру описанному в [этой](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples#masterdetail)
статье. При этом при попытке обновить данные в БД выдается исключение о не закрытом DataReader'е, так же почему то дублируются уже имеющиеся записи в таблице. Ниже приведен мой код. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть дело?

WPF XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Kazna.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Kazna"

    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="SalaryDataProvider" ObjectType="{x:Type local:SalaryDataProvider}"/>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Salary" ObjectInstance="{StaticResource SalaryDataProvider}" MethodName="GetSalary"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Salary}}"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

C#

```
public class KaznaDataProvider
{
    private static KaznaDataSet kaznaDataSet;

    public static KaznaDataSet KaznaDataSet
    {
        get
        {
            if (kaznaDataSet == null)
                kaznaDataSet = new KaznaDataSet();
            return KaznaDataProvider.kaznaDataSet;
        }
    }
}

public class SalaryDataProvider
{
    private SalaryTableAdapter adapter;

    public SalaryDataProvider()
    {
        KaznaDataSet dataset = KaznaDataProvider.KaznaDataSet;

        adapter = new SalaryTableAdapter();
        adapter.Fill(KaznaDataProvider.KaznaDataSet.Salary);

        dataset.Salary.SalaryRowChanged +=
            new KaznaDataSet.SalaryRowChangeEventHandler(SalaryRowModified);
        dataset.Salary.SalaryRowDeleted +=
            new KaznaDataSet.SalaryRowChangeEventHandler(SalaryRowModified);
    }

    void SalaryRowModified(object sender, KaznaDataSet.SalaryRowChangeEvent e)
    {
        adapter.Update(KaznaDataProvider.KaznaDataSet.Salary);
    }

    public DataView GetSalary()
    {
        return KaznaDataProvider.KaznaDataSet.Salary.DefaultView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

В примере на codeproject используется не статический DataSet измените код KaznaDataProvider так чтобы он создавал инстанс  KaznaDataSet. Вообще использование синглтона без реальной необходимости приводит к нехорошим последствиям.

```
public class CustomerDataProvider  
{
    private CustomersTableAdapter adapter;

    private NorthwindDataSet dataset;

    public CustomerDataProvider()
    {
        dataset = new NorthwindDataSet();
        adapter = new CustomersTableAdapter();
        adapter.Fill(dataset.Customers);
    }

    public DataView GetCustomers()
    {
        return dataset.Customers.DefaultView;
    }
}
```